# 'DataFrame' object is not callable in apriori function

Tags: dataframe, apriori

When calling the apriori function I am receiving a "data frame is not callable".

`from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori`

`frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.07, use_colnames=True)`

basket_sets is this one:

[basket_sets columns, columns types and type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y6n3.png)

[basket_sets data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT1yN.png)

The csv was saved with:
`basket_sets.to_csv('./visits/datax/basket_sets' +'.csv' , encoding='utf-8', header=True, index=False , sep=',')`

And is available at:
[dataset CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epywJ8DlfRbbRgM0cmSKAcWBuKgR3X_D/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey it would be great if you also specify the library that you called the apriori function from.

Comment: Thanks. I did it now!